# Using USER:PASS txt file to Textboxes

Tags: vb.net, listbox

How would I got about importing a txt file with login details formatted like -

```
USERNAME1:PASSWORD1
USERNAME2:PASSWORD2
USERNAME3:PASSWORD3
```

I want to import the text file, then have the USER go into one textbox and the PASSWORD go into the other. Sorry if this is worded poorly, I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm completely lost when it comes to this.

This is kinda what I'm trying to do in a really dumb way -

```
                    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
                TextBox1.text = (IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))
    if TextBox1.text contains (":") then 
    TextBox2.text = (Text After The :)
    TextBox1.text = (Text Before the :)
Do all the functions with that login
Then read the next line and use that pair login details (USERNAME2:PASSWORD2)
```

Thanks heaps!

(Sorry for changing the question)

Comment: What '"doesn't work"? In your example (I've edited to make valid syntax), the syntax was incorrect/invalid. Is that all it is? Invalid syntax?

Comment: A `ListBox` can't display text on multiple lines for a single item by default.  If you want that then you'll have to owner-draw the items.

Comment: poor teachers...

Answer (score 0):

There are of course obvious problems for serious applications if you don't encrypts usernames and passwords. In its simplest form this code should do the trick..

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Users = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    For Each userLine As String In Users
        TextBox1.Text = userLine.Split(":"c)(0)
        TextBox2.Text = userLine.Split(":"c)(1)
        'do all the functions with that login
    Next
```

the line ..

```
TextBox1.Text = userLine.Split(":"c)(0)
```

probably needs a little explanation.

The code `userLine.Split(":"c)` returns an array (of 2 elements in your case). Element 0 will be the user name and element 1 will be the password, and the bit at the end `(0)` and `(1)` accesses the appropriate element.

There are more readable ways of doing this, and also if your code is going to get more complex, you would be better using a Structure or a Class to represent each user. For now though, this should serve your needs.